# import openOffice calc in reference in c#

Tags: c#

I want to import an excel file into c#. But problem is, when I want to add reference, so I can use these commands

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interoop;
using Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

there is no such reference.

Comment: You need to have the extension Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) installed on your machine to be able to add those references. They show up under "Assemblies - Extensions".

Comment: Firstly, `Microsoft.Office.Interop` is NOT related to OpenOffice.
Secondly, if you still want to add it, you have to have MS Office Installed on your machine. In Solution Explorer, right click the References item in the tree, select "Add Reference". In "Extensions" find Office extensions (e.g. `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` for example)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use (or don't have) Excel on your machine, use OpenXML for reading Excel content (only new format, xlsx and xlsm). It is a bit more complicated for first look but small and very fast.